# "Broad host permissions" error, despite me having narrow host permissions

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

When I publish Chrome extension, I get the below warning. I'm not requesting broad host permissions, just permissions on 8 specific domains:

> Because of the following issue, your extension may require an in-depth
>   review:
>   - Broad host permissions Instead of requesting broad host permissions, consider using the activeTab permission, or specify the sites that
>   your extension needs access to. Both options are more secure than
>   allowing full access to an indeterminate number of sites, and they may
>   help minimize review times.
>
> The activeTab permission allows access to a tab in response to an
>   explicit user gesture.

```
{   
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "My Amazing Extension", 
    "version": "1.3",
    "description": "It's great", 
    "icons": {
        "16": "img/icon16.png",
        "32": "img/icon32.png",
        "48": "img/icon48.png",
        "128": "img/icon128.png"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "My Amazing Extensions"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [
    {
        "run_at": "document_start",
        "matches": ["*://www.domain.com/*", "*://www.domain.co.uk/*", "*://www.domain.ca/*", "*://www.domain.de/*", "*://www.domain.fr/*", "*://www.domain.es/*", "*://www.domain.it/*", "*://www.domain.in/*"],
        "js": ["content0.js"]
    }],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "font.css",
        "AZSDstyle.css",
        "font.woff2",
        "img/*"
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "storage",
        "*://www.domain.com/*",
        "*://www.domain.co.uk/*",
        "*://www.domain.ca/*",
        "*://www.domain.de/*",
        "*://www.domain.fr/*",
        "*://www.domain.es/*",
        "*://www.domain.it/*",
        "*://www.domain.in/*"
    ],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Comment: The manifest is fine indeed. The message was probably automatically generated which means their detector is buggy and it gets confused by something in your manifest. Maybe `*` in place of the scheme - try listing both http and https explicitly. Or maybe something else in the manifest triggers it. No one knows and it's highly unlikely you'll get a real web store developer looking in your problem. Use divide-and-conquer approach: remove parts of the manifest until it's accepted, then you'll at least know the cause.

Comment: Thanks. Happy to accept that as an answer if you submit one. I think you're right because I've literally just had the extension published after about 30 mins. Normally this takes a week for genuine 'broad host permissions' warnings

Comment: Any idea if the `*` in the scheme was the culprit? I also have narrow permissions but use a `*` in the scheme

Comment: @charlieb Yes I believe it was. See answer. I think a * is fine technically, but the detector is a bit buggy. Maybe that's fixed now as it's been a year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) mentions in his comment, it was likely being rejected because the detector is a bit buggy, potentially because of * in the scheme.

In my case the extension was approved within 30 mins which is unusually quick if there had been actual 'broad permissions' issues which in past experience have taken a week or more to be approved.

Replacing `*://` with `http://` and `https://` on separate lines would likely have avoided this error in the first place.